# Does Flutter have an equivalent command to Python's `pass` keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

All I need to do with my code is if it passes the `if` statement, it simply passes the class and moves on to the rest of the code, but in my research, I can't exactly figure out what the command may be. Is there a way to implement Python's [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) keyword in dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add empty curly braces `{}`. For example:

```
const num = 5;

if (num == 5) {
    
}
```

you don't have to provide code within the curly braces, it can be left empty.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct equivalent to the pass statement in Dart language. In Python, there are language restrictions that do not allow leaving empty loops, if statements and so on. However, in Dart it's completely OK to do that, you can just leave empty braces. For instance:

```
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Ignored
  }

  try {
    // Some logic
  } on Exception {
    // Ignored
  }

  if (true) {
    // Ignored
  }
}
```

There are even some lint rules that check for you not to leave empty logic (you can still add a comment and not leave them empty, though): [empty_statements](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/empty_statements.html), [empty_catches](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/empty_catches.html) and so on.